# cant get data from database with mysqli

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I can not figure out why this code is not working. Im trying to create a temp table and pull some data into it then filter some data out. But i cant seem to echo the data it just echos the column name. Here is the code:

```
if (!$conn) {
    echo "<a href='getschedule.php'><button>Go Back</button></a>";
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

}else{
    echo "Connected successfully<br><br>";
}
$seasontemp = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE seasontemp (
id int NOT NULL,
firstname varchar(255),
lastname varchar(255),
number varchar(255),
address varchar(255),
plan_start date NOT NULL,
plan_comp int(11),
plan_skip int(11),
trim_start date,
trim_comp int(11),
trim_skip int(11),
spray_start date,
spray_comp int(11),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
)";

mysqli_query($conn, $seasontemp) or die ("Sql error : ".mysqli_error($conn));

$insertseason = "INSERT INTO seasontemp
    (id, plan_start, plan_comp, plan_skip, trim_start, trim_comp, spray_start, spray_comp)
SELECT id, plan_start, plan_comp, plan_skip, trim_start, trim_comp, spray_start, spray_comp
FROM services WHERE plan='17'";

mysqli_query($conn, $insertseason) or die ("Sql error : ".mysqli_error($conn));

$seasonids = "SELECT 'id', 'plan_start' FROM seasontemp";
$r1 = mysqli_query($conn, $seasonids ) or die ("Sql error : ".mysqli_error($conn));
if(mysqli_num_rows($r1) > 0){
$start = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r1);
$start_date = $start['plan_start'];
echo $start_date;

}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: so your create table is not working ?

Comment: you didn't inserted anything  in your table. your insert query is wrong

Comment: Insert is not working dude Study on How to insert the data Firstly

Comment: it seems to be i can pull data from it but not the data i want. its ill echo the column name like 'id' or 'plan_start'

Comment: Your table create is correct, but your insert query is wrong so no record inserted in table, and when no record in the table then how it will able to show any record. Check insert query code:- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: Always remember : When you play with queries, before writing in code, you must run query in sql command prompt to check query is working fine or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT 'id', 'plan_start' FROM seasontemp";
```

Replace it with:

```
"SELECT `id`, `plan_start` FROM seasontemp"; // wrong quotes added here.
```

Comment: word thanks dude. I was like WHAT?! I knew my insert query wasnt wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `"SELECT 'id', 'plan_start' FROM seasontemp";` with `"SELECT id, plan_start FROM seasontemp";`

NOTE: Remove single quote of fields otherwise use "`" not "'".

Answer (score 0):

you check Your Insert query is Correct ?

```
$insertseason = "INSERT INTO seasontemp
(id, plan_start, plan_comp, plan_skip, trim_start, trim_comp, spray_start, spray_comp)
SELECT id, plan_start, plan_comp, plan_skip, trim_start, trim_comp, spray_start, spray_comp
FROM services WHERE plan='17'";
```

i think wrong insert query .correct it